# Archiving folder and node jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins seems to archive jobs on the master node. The problem is archive are quite big, and the master node is used for several service. So it is not the right place for this data.

Is there any configuration or plugin I can use to set up archiving locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a custom location for storing build data (which includes the archives) via `Manage Jenkins` -> `Configure System` -> Advanced -> `Build Record Root Directory`.

There is not simple way to *only* move the build *archive* data to a different place. It will be best to switch to a different storage method instead, e.g., use [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/).

Comment: description : *"Specify where Jenkins would store records of the past builds"*. Indeed I want to keep the archive and the record together. This is enough for me.